# Making CakePHP work with SQL server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, cakephp, driver

I can call SQL server 2008 from PHP with [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20098) But as Sqlsvr driver class is needed to use CakePHP with SQL server 2008, I got the driver file from [following repository](https://github.com/revathskumar/CakePHP-sqlsrv-driver).

However, when running my test cakephp with following database.php

```
 <?php
 class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'sqlsvr',
    'host' => 'localhost\EPHP',
    'login' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'database' => 'Blog',
    );
  }
  ?>
```

I got following error:

> Fatal Error (256): ConnectionManager::loadDataSource - Unable to import DataSource class .DboSqlsvr [CORE\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php, line 185]

Then I have read all the [you-cannot-make-cakePHP-work-with-sql-2008 discussions](http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/aa6da91e842e6e9f). Is there any resolution by now?

**UPDATE: Let me rephrase my question. I would appreciate if someone successfully made CakePHP work with SQL 2008 and tell me the procedure he followed to do that.**

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/cakephp/datasources

Comment: Arjan, I have whatever the lastest version is (1.3.11).

Comment: RSK yup, That's the first thing I did and got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found this article ( http://book.cakephp.org/view/1652/Plugin-DataSources-and-Datasource-Drivers). Basically, you can not place your driver file in the directory ( \cakephp\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo) where the "factory" driver files are located. Instead you should place the driver file in following directory of your baked cake.

```
 your-cake-application\plugins\your-plugin-name\models\datasources\dbo
```

And then you should change your database.php in config accordingly.

```
 <?php
 class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'your-plugin-name.DboSqlsrv',
    'host' => 'localhost\EPHP',
    'login' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'database' => 'Blog',
    );
  }
  ?>
```

After this, I could run my cakephp app.

Comment: I'm actually have the same problem you had previously. I've put `dbo_sqlsrv.php` in `my_site\plugins\plugin_name\models\datasources\dbo`. I also set up `database.php` as you have in this post. Is there anything else (code, external files, etc.)? It still doesn't work for me. I get an error that says `SQL Error: An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the datasources in the folder app/model/datasource/dbo_sqlsrv.php load it like this:

```
  <?php
 class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    var $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'sqlsvr',
    'host' => 'localhost\EPHP',
    'login' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'database' => 'Blog',
    );
  }
  ?>
```

The difference is in the 'driver' vs 'datasource' keyword

Comment: José, have you ever made this (cakephp with sql server 2008) work? Unfortunately, I tried it before, it didn't work. And out of desperation, I just now did it again in vain.

Comment: Yes, if you keep getting the same error is because you have the datasource placed in a wrong location. Where is it located?

Comment: I have the file in the place where you suggested. d:\cakePHP\app\models\datasources\dbo_sqlsrv.php

Comment: Jose, although your file location was not right (I guess driver does not work as datasource any more), your tip on location of the file shed some light and I eventually fixed the problem. For that, + 1.