# CakePHP 2, EasyPHP 12 (PHP 5.3.14), MS SQL 2005 Express

Tags: sql-server, cakephp

MS SQL Server is my most familiar DBMS.  I'm really new to PHP and I want to implement small in-house web application (for up to 10 clients), so I decided to use a PC with windows XP SP3 running EasyPHP as my web server.

I think CakePHP is the best approch for MVC web application unfortunately CakePHP supports MySQL out of the box.

Is it possible using CakePHP to connect the MS SQL???, I'm fine to upgrade to the new version of MS SQL.

Please advise.
Thanks.
Kongthap

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with CakePHP, but I see two possible solutions here, which both requires that you install [SqlSrv for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) and [SQL Server Native Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937733.aspx) :

1. Use PDO, SqlSrv provides a PDO driver for SQL Server. If CakePHP supports PDO, you will be able to use it to connect to your SQL Server
2. Use [this driver](https://github.com/revathskumar/CakePHP-sqlsrv-driver) (if still supported by Cake)

Also, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970880/making-cakephp-work-with-sql-server-2008) which seems to address the same kind of issue as yours.